# Unexpected ClassCastException... using EJB

Tags: ejb-3.0, classcastexception

I am facing a very small problem which is driving me mad..

I am calling a business method 'public List getPsubcategoryList()' from a stateless sessionbean named SlBrowseProducts .. this method used entitymanager instance to retrieve a list of Objects from Database Table mapped to Entity class named Psubcategory. this I did using a namedQuery. The list returned contains elements of type Object, I have to attach a iterator named myIterator to list and cast eachof the myIterator.next()'s to the type Psubcategory to make the result element useful and run any getters on it. However this casting returned the following error..

**SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: entitybeans.Psubcategory cannot be cast to entitybeans.Psubcategory**

I tried googling extensively to find the cause for it.. to which I came across something called 'ClassLoader Hell' which might be causing it..

Is there any solution to this problem. Is there any other way around this... I have tried not using Iterator and instead using for loop ... but even then I have to cast.. which again lands me to the same problem..

Please Help m tight on schedule.

====================JSP PAGE==================

```
List<Psubcategory> subcategoryList1 = slbp.getProductSubcategories();                
if(subcategoryList1.size()!=0){
   for(int i=0;i<subcategoryList1.size();i++){
      Psubcategory temp = subcategoryList1.get(i);
      System.out.print(temp.getSubcategory());
   }
}
```

======================SLBrowseProducts.java======================

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SLBrowseProducts implements TestInterface {

   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("INNOVATIVE-INDOORSPU");
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();    

   @Override
   public List getProductSubcategories(){
      List subcategoryList=em.createNamedQuery("Psubcategory.findAll").getResultList();        
      return subcategoryList;
   }
}
```

Comment: How is your query `Psubcategory.findAll` specified? Why can't you use `createNamedquery(name, resultClass)`? Are you returning a list of `@Entity` classes? Why aren't you using dependency injection and use Persistence?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SLBrowseProducts implements TestInterface {

   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("INNOVATIVE-INDOORSPU");
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();    

   @Override
   public List<Psubcategory> getProductSubcategories(){
         List<Psubcategory> subcategoryList=
                                em.createNamedQuery("Psubcategory.findAll").getResultList();        
      return subcategoryList;
   }
}
============================================================================================
List<Psubcategory> subcategoryList1 = slbp.getProductSubcategories();                
   for(Psubcategory temp : subcategoryList1){
      System.out.print(temp.getSubcategory());
   }
```